# Try::Tiny で ImageMagick の例外を処理するには

Tags: perl, imagemagick

ファイルサーバのようなものを作っています。
PDF ファイルのサムネイルを ImageMagick を使って生成しているのですが、ImageMagick でエラーが出る PDF ファイルがあります。
そのファイルの場合、単にサムネイルを使わないようにしたいのですが、try::tiny で囲んでも期待する結果になりません。

コード

```
try{
    my $image = Image::Magick->new;
    $image->Read("${file}[0]");
    $image->Transform(geometry => $imgsize);
    $image->Write($thumbnail);
    undef($image);
    $image = Image::Magick->new;
    $image->Read($thumbnail);
    $image->Resize($imgsize);
    $image->Write($thumbnail);
    undef($image);
}
catch{
    $ret = "<div class = \"misc\">$ext</div>";
    return $ret;
}
```

出力 HTML ファイル

```
<div class = "item"><div class = "misc"><a href = "_postcard.pdf">.pdf</a></dError: /undefined in findresource
Operand stack:
   --dict:5/14(L)--   F1   9.0   --dict:5/5(L)--   --dict:5/5(L)--   MSGothic-90msp-RKSJ-H   --dict:10/12(ro)(G)--   --nostringval--   CIDFontObject   --dict:6/6(L)--   --dict:6/6(L)--   Adobe-Japan1
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1862   1   3   %oparray_pop   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   1845   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1156/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:106/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:286/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:25/40(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
Error: /undefined in findresource
Operand stack:
   --dict:5/14(L)--   F1   9.0   --dict:5/5(L)--   --dict:5/5(L)--   MSGothic-90msp-RKSJ-H   --dict:10/12(ro)(G)--   --nostringval--   CIDFontObject   --dict:6/6(L)--   --dict:6/6(L)--   Adobe-Japan1
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1862   1   3   %oparray_pop   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   1845   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1156/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:106/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:286/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:25/40(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
iv><input type = "checkbox" name = "cb[]" value = "_postcard.pdf" /><a href = "_postcard.pdf">_postcard.pdf</a></div>
```

単に、catch ブロックのみを返したいのですが・・・。

### 追記

ernix さん、回答ありがとうございます。
以下のように書き換えました。

```
    if(!(-f $thumbnail) or ((-M $thumbnail) > $elapsedtime)){
        $ret = eval{
            my $image = Image::Magick->new;
            $image->Read("${file}[0]");
            $image->Transform(geometry => $imgsize);
            $image->Write($thumbnail);
            undef($image);
            $image = Image::Magick->new;
            $image->Read($thumbnail);
            $image->Resize($imgsize);
            #$image->Resize("120x");
            $image->Write($thumbnail);
            undef($image);
            return "<div class = \"img\"><a href = \"$file\"><img src = \"thumbnail\" class = \"img\" /></a></div>";
        } || do {"<div class = \"misc\">$ext</div>";
        };
        return $ret;
    }
    if(-f $thumbnail){
        $ret = "<div class = \"img\"><a href = \"$file\"><img src = \"$thumbnail\" class = \"img\" /></a></div>";
    }
    else{
        $ret = "<div class = \"misc\">$ext</div>";
    }
```

同じエラーが出ます。
教えていただいた回答が私には難しすぎるようです…。

Comment: Try::Tiny にはこだわっていません。
eval も同じようなことができるんでしたっけ?

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.022;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Try::Tiny;

sub wrong {
    try {
        die "ERROR";
    }
    catch {
        my $ret = "CATCH";
        return $ret;
    };  # 最後の";"を忘れずに

    return "try/catch からの `return` はサブルーチンを抜けない。";
}

sub right {
    return try {  # ここにreturnが入るとサブルーチンから抜ける。
        die "ERROR";
    }
    catch {
        my $ret = "CATCH";
        return $ret;
    };

    return "この行には到達しない。";
}

sub using_eval {
    my $ret = eval {
        die "ERROR";

        #
        # 上のコードが死ななかった場合に、
        # `|| do`以下のブロックを評価しないよう1を返す。
        #
        # ブロック内でreturnを書くとサブルーチンのreturnと混同しやすいので、
        # returnは書かず単に最後に評価させるのが望ましい。
        #
        1;
    } || do {
        "ブロックでは、returnが無い場合最後に評価された値が返る。";
    };

    return $ret;
}

say wrong();
say right();
say using_eval();

1;
```